# how to access files on local file system from deployed web app?

Tags: java, windows, tomcat

I have a web app deployed on Tomcat on Windows 7.  I have various files on the PC, local file system, that I want to access from my web app.  How can I do this or is this possible?

Comment: The file system of the server or the client?

Comment: Stream them through a servlet (or whatever framework you're using, most have a mechanism for doing this). Assuming you mean files local to the webapp.

Comment: in this case they are one and the same.  But particularly on the server, the local file system the Tomcat runs on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, looks like I found the solution.

Can just use the File() object with absolute paths and that does the trick.

I thought there would be some special requirements for web apps but it looks like there isn't